# MS Access 2007 popup form refuses to display/not accessible in design mode (but present in list of forms)

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Having a problem with MS Access 2007 refusing to display a form in design mode.  I can see the code for the form (if I go through the event properties of a button that displays the form), but I cannot see the form laid out as a GUI. And, when I try and invoke this form from the application's main window, it does not display and locks up the whole GUI.

Now, I tried putting debug before and after the display of this form, and the debug does get invoked.

Anyone have any ideas?  I tried looking at the Trust Center, and I set "Enable all Macros", but that didn't seem to matter.

Answer (score 3):

A few steps I would take:

1. Make sure your form has the `Auto Center`, `Auto Resize` properties set to `Yes`.
   I had an issue once with forms that opened outside the visible screen, Quite baffling.
   Also try to change its `PopUp` and `Modal` properties to it becomes just a normal non-blocking form for your tests.
2. Your database may be corrupted.
   Make a copy of your database and then decompile and compact it.
   You can do that from the command line, for instance:

   ```
   "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\msaccess.exe" "D:\Code\mydb.accdb" /decompile /compact
   ```
3. Export the VBA + Form resource, then delete the form from your Access client, then do the decompile+compact above again, then re-import the form.

   ```
   ' Export form and VBA to text files '
   Application.SaveAsText acForm, "myForm", "myForm.txt"

   ' Import form and VBA from text files '
   Application.LoadFromText, "myNewForm", "myForm.txt"
   ```